# Premake linkingLinking into SharedLib not working

Tags: c++, glfw, premake

I am currently trying to learn C++ and thought doing some OpenGL magic would be a nice idea.
I saw a Premake5 tutorial and followed along, except I tried linking a library myself (GLFW).
When generating the project files for Visual Studio 2017, the library I specified somehow does not get properly linked into the project.
I get lots a lots of LINK errors in the likes of:

> glfw3.lib(monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp__strdup" in Funktion "_glfwAllocMonitor".
>
> glfw3.lib(win32_window.c.obj) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp__strdup".
>
> ...

This is how my premake5.lua file looks like:

```
workspace "MojoEngine"
architecture "x64"

configurations
{
    "Debug",
    "Release",
    "Dist"
}

outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}"

project "MojoEngine"
location "MojoEngine"
kind "SharedLib"
language "C++"

targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

librarydir = "%{prj.name}/libraries/"

files
{
    "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
    "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp"
}

includedirs
{
    librarydir .. "GLFW/include",
    "%{prj.name}/vendor/spdlog/include"
}

libdirs
{
    librarydir .. "GLFW/lib"
}

links
{
    "glfw3",
    "glfw3dll"
}

filter "system:windows"
    cppdialect "C++17"
    staticruntime "On"
    systemversion "latest"

    defines
    {
        "ME_PLATFORM_WINDOWS",
        "ME_BUILD_DLL"
    }

    postbuildcommands
    {
        ("{COPY} %{cfg.buildtarget.relpath} ../bin/" .. outputdir .. 
    "/Sandbox"),
        ("{COPY} %{prj.name}/lib/GLFW/glfw3.dll ../bin/" .. outputdir .. 
    "/Sandbox")
    }

filter "configurations:Debug"
    defines "ME_DEBUG"
    symbols "On"

filter "configurations:Release"
    defines "ME_RELEASE"
    optimize "On"

filter "configurations:Dist"
    defines "ME_DIST"
    optimize "On"

project "Sandbox"
location "Sandbox"
kind "ConsoleApp"
language "C++"

targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

files
{
    "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
    "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp"
}

includedirs
{
    "MojoEngine/vendor/spdlog/include",
    "MojoEngine/src"
}

links
{
    "MojoEngine"
}

filter "system:windows"
    cppdialect "C++17"
    staticruntime "On"
    systemversion "latest"

    defines
    {
        "ME_PLATFORM_WINDOWS",
    }

filter "configurations:Debug"
    defines "ME_DEBUG"
    symbols "On"

filter "configurations:Release"
    defines "ME_RELEASE"
    optimize "On"

filter "configurations:Dist"
    defines "ME_DIST"
    optimize "On"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the glfw documentation. There it says you have to link some windows specific libraries for different compiler versions.

> [GLFW Documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/build.html#build_link):
>
> When linking a program under Windows that uses the static version of
> GLFW, you must link with opengl32. On some versions of MinGW, you must
> also explicitly link with gdi32, while other versions of MinGW include
> it in the set of default libraries along with other dependencies like
> user32 and kernel32. If you are using GLU, you must also link with
> glu32.

If you use MinGW you might need to link gdi32 to your "MojoEngine" project.

***Note:*** You are linking dynamically, so you need to link opengl32. Sorry misread that.